# Google Chart printing vAxis format selector as well as number

Tags: google-visualization

I have a really simple implementation of a classic google line chart but when applying `vAxis: { format: 'none' }` it is printing **none** to the chart as well as correctly formatting the number.

Going through the documentation I have tried `options['vAxis']['format'] = 'none'` just to see if that would magically solve it for me but to no success.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'line'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Day of Week');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Pressure');

  //console.log(outer[0]);
  data.addRows(outer[0]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
    title: 'Pressure Forecast',
    subtitle: ''
    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    vAxis: {
      format: 'none'
    }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('pressureChart'));
chart.draw(data, options);}
```

[image]

Comment: `'none'` is not a valid number format, if you simply want the number and no commas or decimals, use --> `format: '0'`

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat I will try that.  I must say that the documentation does suggest otherwise which is a tad confusing.

{format: 'none'}: displays numbers with no formatting (e.g., 8000000)

Answer (score 0):

@WhiteHat was correct vAxis: { format: '0' } has done as needed and overridden the default of { format: 'short' }.

```
function drawChart() {
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
 data.addColumn('string', 'Day of Week');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Pressure');

 //console.log(outer[0]);
 data.addRows(outer[0]);

 var options = {
  chart: {
    title: 'Pressure Forecast',
    subtitle: ''
  },
 width: 900,
 height: 500,
 vAxis: {
   format: '0'
 }
};
```